# Why can't I create a scalar property on my edmx?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, edmx

I'm in the edmx editor of visual studio, and I have a column that I want to map to a new property.

So I right click on my entity -> add -> new scalar property.

And the instead of adding the entity , the IDE goes to the Mapping details windows and select me the Column that isn't mapped.

Did you ever encounter this kind of bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your model. Close Visual Studio. Start Visual Studio and open your edmx.

Now it should work (did it for me.)

Consider it a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: Indeed it's a visual studio bug, should be resolved in 2012 though